# Execute program over PHP at Windows

Tags: php, windows, ssh

I want to try to execute a program that is based on my Windows PC over a PHP command.
I got an static IP where I can connect to.
I installed the Bitvise SSH Server and I can connect with the Bitvise SSH Client to it. There I can run things over the CMD.

But I wanted to connect through a PHP script to the CMD (over SSH) and giving it commands. (i.e. to restart the pc)

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php may be what you're looking for. The question is too vague to know for sure though.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

Comment: What do I need on my Windows PC to execute the Shell commands?